# Password to save the QGIS project

Tags: qgis

I have a project in QGIS that many other people have access to, but sometimes it happens that someone can save it by accident and I then need to restore it to the way it was.

Is it possible to set a password to save the project in QGIS.

Comment: A simple way is to set the qgz file read only. In Windows just right click it and Properties

Answer (score 1):

I think No, this feature is possible using access control from filesystem or your OS, for example via ActiveDirectory or other systems.
If you want to crypt or control access and permission to edit your file, you have do use external applications. In Qgis this is not implemented too and no issue or pull requests to qgis opensource [repository](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS) is pending for this.